# How to write output as a separate file under existing HDFS directory using Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I have a use case where I need to write output as a separate file under existing HDFS directory. When I use sparkContext.saveAsHadoopFile() method, an exception is thrown saying output directory already exists. Currently, I'm able to do it using Hadoop client library and launch it as a Spark's task, below is the code sample code snippet. I was wondering if we can do this job using Spark's library functions?

Code using standard Hadoop client library.

```
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(getHDFSConfiguration(hadoopConf))
val outputFile = new Path(newPath)

hdfs.createNewFile(outputFile)

hdfs.append(outputFile)
      .writeBytes(content)
```

Spark version : 2.3.x

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Hadoop with version > 0.20.0, you can set this property in your hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.support.append</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>
```

and then you can use .append of FileSystem, to add the data to the existing data path.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a dataframe and save its data to a file as

```
df.write.mode("append").csv("pathToFile")
```

Please be aware that if you don't set the coalesce to 1, you will get some files instead of one single file. To do so, you need to

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").csv("pathToFile")
```

I assume that you want to save data as csv, but there are other multiple formats like parquet, avro, orc, etc. that are more efficient in some aspects than csv